# laravel 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I got 500 internal server error when i trying perform Ajax post, please help.

```
       @foreach($influencer->categories as $category)
        <div class ="cat_sec" cid="{{ $category->id }}">
        <tr><td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_button" href="{{ route('ajax_remove_cat',  array('inf_id'=>$influencer->id,'cat_id'=>$category->id)) }}">Remove</a></td>                                                                      
        </tr>
        <div>

  @endforeach


    @section('scripting')
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.remove_button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
     url:myurl,
     type:'POST',
    }).done(function() {
      var response = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
      var element = $("[cid='"+(response.cat_id)+"']");
      $(element).removeClass('cat_sec');

    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Failure! "+jqxhr.responseText);
    });
  });



</script>
@stop
```

and for controller,

```
public function ajax_remove_cat(Request $request, $inf_id, $cat_id) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $agent = $user->getTypeModel();
    $influencer = $this->influencer->findBYId($inf_id);

    DB::table('categories_influencers')->where('categories_id', $cat_id)->delete();

    if($request->ajax()) {

        return response()->json(array('responsecode'=>'1','action'=>'delete','cat_id'=>$request->route('cat_id')));
 }

}
```

i am newbie to laravel, really have no idea where is the problem is , please help me get through this.

Comment: Share, please, server error text (see error_log if you use Apache httpd)

Comment: Does your code work when you try to call `myurl` manually? One common  cause for error code 500 with Laravel is a missing `RewriteBase /` line in `.htaccess`.

Comment: its be solved!, change type post to get. thanks guys

Comment: Look at this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318719/laravel-ajax-returns-500-internal-server-error/37340984#37340984) Without the error itself we can only guess

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get 500 Error is that by default Laravel uses its [HTTP Middleware to protect against CSRF attacks](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection). You need to include a `_token` containing your `csrf_token()` value.
Don't just resort to get if it is better to use post. For example, what happens if you actually navigate to that route?