# Laravel ajax returns 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Laravel ajax returns 500 (Internal Server Error). Could you tell me what is the problem?

**sample.brade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input.dog_check").click(function(){
  var amount = 10000;
  var dataString = 'amount='+amount;
  console.log(dataString);
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url: 'save_temporary_data',
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/save_temporary_data', 'PaymentsController@saveTemporaryData');
```

**PaymentsController.php**

```
~~~
public function saveTemporaryData(){
    if (Request::ajax()){
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $insert = "insert into　temporary_data values('$amount')";// Do Your Insert Query
        if(mysql_query($insert)) {
         echo "Success";
        } else {
         echo "Cannot Insert";
        }
    }
}
~~~
```

**update** 
I added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and the following into `sample.blade.php`. However it cannot solve the problem.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

**sample.blade.php**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/edit_profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/host_profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/validationEngine.jquery.css">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>

~~~

$("input.dog_check").click(function(){
  var amount = 10000;
  var dataString = 'amount='+amount;
  console.log(dataString);
  $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url: 'save_temporary_data',
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error-500-internal-server-error?rq=1)

Comment: Take a look in `/storage/logs` to see what error has occurred and post it here. Also, if you are using Laravel, why not use eloquent or the querybuilder?

Comment: Yes check you logs it wills how you right away what issue there is

Answer (score 2):

Without the error nobody can't do anything
You can Check your logs manually. in /storage/logs.
But if you want to see the error "on site" Do the following.
Before you submit open the developer console and go to the networking tab.
submit the ajax request. And you will get the red request in the networking tab.
Click on it, and on the right side there is the preview tab.
In the preview tab will be the laravel formatted message.
Hope this helps with your debugging

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<script>
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :"{{url('save_temporary_data')}}",
            data:{_token: CSRF_TOKEN,amount:amount},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
</script>
```

in route file

```
Route::post('/save_temporary_data','PaymentsController@saveTemporaryData');
```

in controller

```
public function saveTemporaryData(Request $request){
   echo $request['amount'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by referencing the following page. Thank [ajax post in laravel 5 return error 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154489/ajax-post-in-laravel-5-return-error)‌​-500-internal-server-error?rq=1