# laravel and react upload file return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

i have a problem with my code when I try to upload a file with `reactjs` and `laravel` for backend, after click submit button server response with 500 IS error,looking forward inside code i get message Call to a member function `getClientOriginalName()` on null, I guess error appear because of my `js` function, so hopefully someone can help me finger it out, i am appreciate it

my react component :

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.fileInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        avatar: '',
    }
}

handleNameChange(e){
    this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    })
}


handleAvatarChange(e){
    this.setState({
        avatar:this.fileInput.current.files[0].name
    })
}


handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/api/add', this.state).then(response => {
        console.log(response)

    }).then(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <a href="/">home</a>
            {/*<Link to="/" className="btn btn-success">Return to Items</Link>*/}
            <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" value={this.state.name}  onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>

                <input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} onChange={this.handleAvatarChange.bind(this)} /><br></br>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

}

}
```

my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $file_name_image = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
    $user = new User();

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user ->avatar = $file_name_image;
    $request->file('avatar')->move('upload/',$file_name_image);
    $user->save();
    return response()->json('Successfully added');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534778/laravel-500-internal-server-error?rq=1

Comment: you need to send form data and also add headers

Comment: can you sugguest some code, i am newbie with react, it 's very complicate for me

Comment: You will find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react

Comment: @Gary thank you! it work but only insert file into database,now i want to add more description or name etc? how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your input tag.
Input doesn't have name attribute. You should add it.

```
    <input name="file" type="text" className="form-control" id="name" value={this.state.name}  onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>
```

And I recommend you add IF statement in yours controller.

```
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
       //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment, so I will write the answer here.
So you can find the answer for your original question here: [How do I set multipart in axios with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react)

If you want to send other data than file too, you just simply add it like you did with the file. for example:

```
formData.append('name', 'Your new name')
```

first parameter is the name you want for the POST data key, the second one is the data you want to send. It can come from the state etc.

Comment: thank you! it working, i put my answer on secssion bellow

Comment: if you find it useful please don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who may need, thank all!

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        file:null,
        name:'',
    }
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
}

onFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
    this.fileUpload(this.state.file,this.state.name).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response.data);
    })
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
}

handleNameChange(e){
    this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    })
}


fileUpload(file, name){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/add';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',file);
    formData.append('name', name);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    return  post(url, formData,config)
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <h1>File Upload</h1>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.name}  onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```